# "TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String" on HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have to deal with this error when I try to associate a record to another one via a HABTM association:

```
Person.first.communities = Communities.all
```

Models and migrations:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

 class CreateCommunities < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :communities do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.text :description

       t.timestamps null: false
     end
   end
 end

class CreateJoinTablePersonCommunity < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :people, :communities do |t|
      # t.index [:person_id, :community_id]
      # t.index [:community_id, :person_id]
    end
  end
end
```

I use the `pg (0.18.4)` gem with the `Postgres (9.5.2)`

Comment: Could you also show your models for related associations?

Answer (score 0):

Youcan use below code to create relationship.

```
Person.first.communities << Communities.all
```

If this not works please check your associations via reflect association method on the model.